# Is it a good practice to return a boolean/value instead of null in case of no-ops?

Tags: java, design-patterns, boolean

This observation was made after looking at `addNode` code in  [DirectedGraph.java](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=dijkstra). The coder has used a true and a false to distinguish a no-op from an op. A similar example is the code below custom made simply to ask my question easily. Is it a recommended / good practice to return boolean to differentiate and no-op from an op  to give more visibility to the client of code ?

```
public class FreeMain {

    private List<Integer> fooList;

    FreeMain ( ) {  }

    /**
     * Lazy init - either set a value of no-op.
     * 
     * @param barList
     */
    public void putList(List<Integer> barList) {
        if (this.fooList == null) {
            this.fooList = barList;
        }
    }



    /**
     * Boolean returned as an indication to the user of operation status
     * 
     * @param barList 
     * @return true if putLists sets the value, false is no-op.
     */
    public boolean putListWithBoolean(List<Integer> barList) {
        if (this.fooList == null) {
            this.fooList = barList;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you *do* actually mean `null` here right? Just confused because the snippet has an example with return type `void` (i.e. not returning anything at all)

Comment: My personal opinion is absolutely not. Return bool if you're answering a question that can only ever be true or false. Typically properties or methods that are prefixed with "Is" (Eg IsConnected)

Comment: @Jeff lets take example of Linkedlist remove. It returns a boolean. with your explanation (if i understodd it correct ) remove is not answering back with a question that can only be true or false ?

Comment: Correct. It can either be removed or it can't. Typically if the item doesn't exist, then the operation becomes a no-op since the desired state has been achieved. If the item can't be removed for some reason (eg a read-only collection) then an exception should be thrown.  If the item can be removed then the successful completion of the operation signifies this to the caller.

Comment: Fair enof. I must say collections has a lots of inconsitencies.

Answer (score 3):

I will set it this way, is the responsibillity of the putList in this case to tell you whether the list you try to put is accepted or not by returning a boolean? In my opinion no, this is because the putList should handle only the single module of replacing the list pointer and not return something.

If you actually want to know whether the conditions are granted or not(or for any ubnormal behavior that could occur), use Exceptions. Then simply catch those exceptions into your main when the putList is used(with try-catch blocks) and do whatever you wish.

For example:

```
public void putList(List<Integer> barList) throws new MyListException{
    if (this.fooList == null) {
        this.fooList = barList;
    } else {
        throw new MyListException("The pointer of fooList can not be changed because the fooList is not null");
    }
}

public class MyListException extends Exception {
    public MyListException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the case that the method would return a true/false is when it should actually handle that module and determine whether a list will be accepted or not by testing the condition. Thus, the method name will be 'isListAccepted()' (a parameter is not needed since it doesnt play any role). However, in java it is noticed (i.e [See LinkedList click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29)) that sometimes methods like public boolean add(E e) returns true/false. This is because those methods are implemented under the collection interface and there are some preconditions in the way the collection works. Additionally, in this case as well oracle documentation says:

> public boolean add(E e) Ensures that this collection contains the specified element 
>   (optional operation). Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the
>   call. (Returns false if this collection does not permit duplicates and
>   already contains the specified element.)
>
> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason
>   other than that it already contains the element, it **must** throw an
>   exception (rather than returning false).

So based on that, I believe that these operations, handle the module of telling you if your collection has changed or not after their use rather than adding the element(even if they do in some cases).

An example:

```
private boolean isListAccepted() {
    return this.fooList == null;
}
```

Finally, since I am not sure too about what do you mean with "instead of null in case of no-operations", I am gonna say that: when you use the `putList(..)` and the condition is not granted, it doesnt return `null`, but rather it is doing nothing. However, it is always preferable in this case as well to use Exceptions as I already demonstrate(in the first example) so that you will know what went wrong in case you expect the putList() to actually replace the pointer. And this is because you wont always have the chance to spend time searching the code to understand what went wrong. This is not really important with the code example you provided since it is simple but what if you had a putList that was more complex and multiple things could go wrong ?

Overall, i can not say if putListWithBoolean() is a bad practice because it depends on the way it is used(as shown with the java example), while the putList() without exceptions can be considered as a bad practice, because your classes wont be that simple always, and many things could go wrong, so you better know what went wrong and where.

Comment: I agree except you should never check something like this a priori to see if it will work. Just do it and then handle (or don't) the exception as you said.